# Add Labels to a bar chart Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

I am trying to add labels to my below Bar chart attached as image and I am using the below code
Could someone please help?

```
#Count of Labels
Count = data.groupby(['kmeans']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
Count
Count.plot(x="kmeans", y=["counts"], kind="bar")

plt.title("Clustering Output grouped by Labels")
plt.xlabel("Labels_Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Total data points")
plt.savefig('label_count_img.png', dpi=1200)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart

Comment: The Matplotlib documentation includes [an example on how to do this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, so I assumed you want to change the name for each bar.

I couldn't tell what your data was, so I just created my own data as an example. Anyways, this is how I did it:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['Label 1', 'Label 2']
data = [419, 337]

plt.bar(x, data)
plt.title("Clustering Output grouped by Labels")
plt.xlabel("Labels_Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Total data points")

plt.show()

plt.savefig('label_count_img.png', dpi=1200)
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.
The code I have pasted in my question works fine but I just want to show labels in the bars (419 in the first bar and 337 in the second bar)